# Creating a view to manage permissions laravel

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-permission

I am trying to create a view on my website where an admin can manage the permission the users have.
I have seen on a few websites you can use spatie to create those permissions, but when I run the command:

```
  composer require spatie/laravel-permission
       composer require laravelcollective/html
```

I get this error:

```
The requested PHP extension ext-mysql * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mysql extension.
```

I tried to run the command directly on the terminal without accessing the project but I do it that way it won't let me do the migration.

I was wondering if there is another way to do it that doesn't involve spartie or if there is any way to fix the problem I get.

The User Controller:

```html
      <?php

      namespace App\Http\Controllers;

       use App\Role;
       use App\User;
       use Illuminate\Http\Request;
       use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

       class UsersController extends Controller
      {

    public function index(Request $request){

        $users = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);

        return view('users.index', compact('users'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    public function show($id){
        $users = User::findorfail($id);

        return view('users.show', compact('users'));
    }

    public function create(){

        $roles=Role::pluck('name', 'name')->all();
        return view('register.create', compact('roles'));

    }

    public function store(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'lastname'=> 'required',
            'email'=> 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password'=> 'required|same:confirm-password',
            'roles'=> 'required',

        ]);

        $input=$request->all();
        $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);

        $user = User::create($input);

        $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));

        return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success', 'User created successfully');
    }


    public function edit ($id){
        $users = User:: findorfail($id);
        $roles = Role::pluck('name', 'name')->all();
        $userRole = $users->roles->pluck('name', 'name')->all();

        return view('users.edit', compact('users', 'roles', 'userRole'));
    }

    public function destroy($id){
        $users = User::findorfail($id);

        $users->delete($id);

        return redirect('/users')->with('User deleted correctly');

    }

    public function update (Request $request, $id){

       $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'lastname'=> 'required',
            'email'=> 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password'=> 'required|same:confirm-password',
            'roles'=> 'required',

        ]);

       $input = $request->all();

       if (!empty($input['password'])){
           $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
       }else{
           $input = array_except($input , array('password'));
       }

        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->update($input);
        $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));

        return redirect('/users/'.$user->id)->with('User updated successfully');
    }
}
```

The Routes file:

```
    <?PHP
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/home', 'ReturnsController@create')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/home', 'ReturnsController@store')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/register/create', 'UsersController@create');
Route::post('/register', 'UsersController@store');
Route::get('/users/create', 'UsersController@create');
Route::post('/users', 'UsersController@store');
Route::get('/users', 'UsersController@index');
Route::get('/users/{users}', 'UsersController@show');
Route::get('/users/{users}/edit', 'UsersController@edit');
Route::delete('/users/{users}/destroy', 'UsersController@destroy')->name('users.destroy');

Route::get('/users/{id}', 'UsersController@edit');

Route::resource('role', 'RoleController');
```

Comment: you need to check your php.ini, extension = php_mysqli.dll, check if it is commented

Comment: @abdel-azizhassan how do I access the php.ini? thank you

Comment: @Becks On the command line execute: `php --ini`.